# How to configure a Angular 5 project running inside a War? Using Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am using the Angular CLI to replace a 3 part AngularJS enterprise application.

The app is structured in this way. I am trying to rewrite app 2-

Login (app1)-> Routing(to 3rd party apps) and User Settings(app2)-> Admin Functionality(app3)

Now the problem I have is that the Java application runs on Port 8080, and the CLI runs on 4200. This isn't that big of a deal, I was able to use proxy.conf.json to get to my dev server.

This is my proxy file-

```
{
    "**":{
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have to run 2 servers, and integration from one app to the next is going to be really problematic. I have to release a prod build, and try to integrate into the other apps. There are cookies, other DOM data issues from using JSP's. Basically, using this workflow is inefficient. But I really like the Angular CLI.

Are there ways to configure the CLI to work around this problem? Should I be trying to setup webpack from scratch? Anyone else come across problems like this? I am a beginner at Webpack, and new to the Angular 5 (2+).

Please help.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem you have. This is a common setup, to have a server running for the API part and Angular CLI for the frontend development.

Answer (score 1):

One good solution is to convert your angular project into a maven project and you can easily create a war from it.

- I used simple webapp.

Directory Structure-

```
AngularApp
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       ├── resources
│       ├── webapp
│       └── angularapp
```

Open pom.xml and configure following three maven plugins:-

- compiler-plugin
- war-plugin
- exec-plugin

you can specify all the build parameters in pom.xml and when you run pom.xml it will generate a war file.

Comment: Sorry, I already have a war file, and a java project that I want to run inside. I want to run it on the same server, ie on port 8080.

Comment: Yes, for that you need to deploy your war file to the any web server or application server and inside the deployment folder where the war file is extracted you need to create a folder and copy the content of dist folder generated by angular build and in the index.html change the basehref tag. Example in apache tomcat  if you deploy the war file, go in tomcat folder -> webapps and create a new folder name say ngApp, copy the content of you dist folder generated by ng build, open index.html and update <base href="./ngApp">. Now you can access angular app at localhost:8080/ngApp.